# Can't resolve "app.js" - Webpack

Tags: javascript, webpack

**Problem**

So, i'm working a web app using Webpack and ES6. When I try to run Webpack, it tells me that it can't resolve "app.js". I've looked all across the internet for a solution, but I just couldn't find one, can someone help me?
The Full error is:

```
ERROR in ./assets/js/main.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'app.js' in 'C:\Users\sidna\Dropbox\Dev Stuff\Web Apps\Mondrian Generator\assets\js'
 @ ./assets/js/main.js 4:0-17
```

**webpack.config.js**

```
module.exports = {
entry: './assets/js/main.js',
output: {
    filename: 'assets/js/build.js',
},
watch: true,
module: {
    loaders: [
        {
            test: /\.scss$/, loader: "style-loader!css-loader!sass-loader"
        },
        {
          test: /\.js$/,
          exclude: /node_modules/,
          use: {
            loader: 'babel-loader',
            options: {
              presets: ['env']
            }
          }
        }
    ],
}
};
```

**app.js (Empty)**

**main.js**

```
// SCRIPTS
require("app.js");

// STYLES
require("../css/large.scss");
```

**package.json**

```
{
"name": "mondrian-generator",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Create your own Mondrian",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "css-loader": "^0.28.0",
    "style-loader": "^0.16.1",
    "webpack": "^2.4.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-loader": "^6.4.1",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.4.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.5.2",
    "sass-loader": "^6.0.3",
    "script-loader": "^0.7.0",
    "webpack": "^2.4.1"
  }
}
```

Comment: Clarify where do you put the files.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When the import is neither an absolute path (starting with `/`) nor explicitly a relative path (starting with `./` or `../`), it is resolved as a module, which means it's [Loading from `node_modules` Folders](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_loading_from_node_modules_folders).

Your `app.js` is not in `node_modules`, so you need to change it to a relative path (assuming it's in the same directory as `main.js`):

```
require("./app.js");
```

Webpack follows the import behaviour of Node.js, but it also allows you to change it with the [`resolve.modules`](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/#resolve-modules) option.